# Bedeutung von Wörtern, die auf "-geil" enden

Tags: meaning

Was bedeuten die Adjektive, die auf *-geil* enden, z. B.:

> geldgeil, auflagengeile (Journalisten), anschlagsgeil (vermutlich Terroristen) usw.

Und gehören diese Wörter zu Umgangssprache/Jugendsprache?

Comment: I can't make sense of "aufladengeil".

Comment: He most likely means "auflagengeil".

Comment: @Em1: Ich nehme an, dass es auflagengeil heißen sollte.

Comment: @raznagul Oder aufgabengeil ;)

Comment: [Dieses Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZUNZbhnoX4) hat viele Anwendungsbeispiele von Adjektiven, die auf *-geil* enden.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An Subjektiven wird mit dem relativ neuen Suffix *-geil* im adjektivischen Gebrauch umgangssprachlich zum Ausdruck gebracht, dass eine Person (in abwertender Wiese) gierig oder versessen auf eine Sache ist.

Nach der [ursprünglichen Bedeutung von geil](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GG05275#XGG05275) (*gierig, froh, fröhlich, mutig, ... etc.*) kommt es interessanterweise dazu, dass bedeutungsähnliche Suffixe (meist *-gierig*) ersetzt werden:

> geldgierig, konsumfreudig, ...

Oft enstehen aber auch völlig neue Bindungen, die dann auch nicht mehr abwertend sind:

> affengeil, megageil, ...

Solche Verbindungen hatten ihren Ursprung auch in der Jugendsprache. Nachdem die damals Jugendlichen mittlerweile aber gar nicht mehr so jung sind, würde ich diesen Begriff heute nicht mehr wählen.

Comment: Wobei zumindest _konsumgeil_ wesentlich negativer klingt als _konsumfreudig_.

Comment: Not a bad answer, but the negative connotation is not mentioned.

Comment: @henning: that is correct - I added a word on that.